# Keyboard event inside a class not working in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, event-handling, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to capture a keypress after a canvas object is displayed in order to delete the latter, and it's not working. The canvas is displayed properly, but the keypress event is not getting captured. I am a total newbie at Python and this is just a test-code to check my understanding of Tkinter so far. I'm sure it's something fairly basic that I'm missing, so thank you for your patience.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # create splash screen
        splash = Canvas(master, bg='white')
        splash.bind("<Key>",self.splash_key)
        splash.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def splash_key(event):
        print('key captured!')
        splash.delete("all")

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Test')
root.attributes('-zoomed',True)
app = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to call `splash.focus_set()` in order to receive the key events.

Comment: Thank you! That worked!